# Hasura: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.23.0.4", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hasura

Trying to follow the Hasura quickstart with Docker from the following link:
https://hasura.io/docs/latest/getting-started/docker-simple/

Here is the docker-compose.yaml file from Docker. I ran it with no changes:

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.32.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      PG_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DEFAULTS: '{"backend_configs":{"dataconnector":{"athena":{"uri":"http://data-connector-agent:8081/api/v1/athena"},"mariadb":{"uri":"http://data-connector-agent:8081/api/v1/mariadb"},"mysql8":{"uri":"http://data-connector-agent:8081/api/v1/mysql"},"oracle":{"uri":"http://data-connector-agent:8081/api/v1/oracle"},"snowflake":{"uri":"http://data-connector-agent:8081/api/v1/snowflake"}}}}'
    depends_on:
      data-connector-agent:
        condition: service_healthy
  data-connector-agent:
    image: hasura/graphql-data-connector:v2.32.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      QUARKUS_LOG_LEVEL: ERROR # FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE
      QUARKUS_OPENTELEMETRY_ENABLED: "false"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/athena/health"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The postgresql and data-connector-agent containers run fine, however the graphql-engine container constanly errors out and restarts.

Here is the error log from the graphql-engine container:

```
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"message":{"host":"Unknown or invalid host","message":"Postgres connection failed","retry_attempt":0}},"level":"warn","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.409+0000","type":"pg-client"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"message":{"host":"Unknown or invalid host","message":"Postgres connection failed","retry_attempt":1}},"level":"warn","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.409+0000","type":"pg-client"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"info":"WARNING: No admin secret provided","kind":"no_admin_secret"},"level":"warn","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.511+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"info":{"admin_secret_set":false,"auth_hook":null,"auth_hook_mode":null,"console_assets_dir":null,"console_sentry_dsn":null,"cors_config":{"allowed_origins":"*","disabled":false,"ws_read_cookie":null},"enable_allowlist":false,"enable_console":true,"enable_maintenance_mode":false,"enable_metadata_query_logging":false,"enable_telemetry":true,"enabled_apis":["config","pgdump","metadata","graphql"],"enabled_log_types":["webhook-log","http-log","startup","query-log","websocket-log"],"events_fetch_batch_size":100,"experimental_features":[],"graceful_shutdown_timeout":60,"infer_function_permissions":true,"jwt_secret":[],"live_query_options":{"batch_size":100,"refetch_delay":1},"log_level":"info","port":8080,"remote_schema_permissions":false,"server_host":"HostAny","stringify_numeric_types":false,"transaction_isolation":"ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED","unauth_role":null,"use_prepared_statements":true,"v1-boolean-null-collapse":false,"websocket_compression_options":"NoCompression","websocket_connection_init_timeout":"Refined (Seconds {seconds = 3s})","websocket_keep_alive":"KeepAliveDelay {unKeepAliveDelay = Refined (Seconds {seconds = 5s})}"},"kind":"server_configuration"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.511+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"info":{"database_url":"postgres://postgres:...@postgres:5432/postgres","retries":1},"kind":"postgres_connection"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.511+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"message":{"host":"Unknown or invalid host","message":"Postgres connection failed","retry_attempt":0}},"level":"warn","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.511+0000","type":"pg-client"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"message":{"host":"Unknown or invalid host","message":"Postgres connection failed","retry_attempt":1}},"level":"warn","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.511+0000","type":"pg-client"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"detail":{"info":{"code":"postgres-error","error":"connection error","internal":"connection to server at \"postgres\" (172.23.0.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"172.23.0.4\", user \"postgres\", database \"postgres\", no encryption\n","path":"$"},"kind":"catalog_migrate"},"level":"error","timestamp":"2023-08-22T00:19:30.511+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-08-21 17:19:30 {"error":"connection error","path":"$","code":"postgres-error","internal":"connection to server at \"postgres\" (172.23.0.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"172.23.0.4\", user \"postgres\", database \"postgres\", no encryption\n"}
```

Here is the log from the postgres container:

```
2023-08-21 17:19:30 2023-08-22 00:19:30.409 UTC [217] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.23.0.4", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
2023-08-21 17:19:30 2023-08-22 00:19:30.511 UTC [218] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.23.0.4", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
2023-08-21 17:19:30 2023-08-22 00:19:30.513 UTC [219] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.23.0.4", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
2023-08-21 17:19:30 2023-08-22 00:19:30.615 UTC [220] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.23.0.4", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
```

I tried running the same process on a coworker's Mac and it worked. For reference, I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad running Windows 11. I tried running on WSL and the same error happened.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by deleting the volume and restarting the process

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).